# jinja2 template in ansible firewalld rule

Tags: ansible, jinja2, var

I'm writing firewalld rules in ansible playbook using richrule in firewalld module. In it I need to use the same rules for different source ip addresses.
For example: In the rule written as,

```
rich_rule= rule family='ipv4' source address='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' protocol value='icmp' accept
```

I need to change the address only. So for that I have to apply different ip addresses by using jinja2 template.
For this I wrote rules in a method as follows:

```
rich_rule= rule family='ipv' source address="{{ lookup('file', './src.txt') }}" protocol value="icmp" accept
```

And trued to execute it by adding ip addresses in the src file. But there I couldn't add more than one address. So for me, several ip addresses should be selected from a text file and the rules should be applied
So is there any way to do this? If anyone knows a method in which it can be done, please help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Also, kindly indent your post properly. It is not clear where the code block starts and where it ends.

Comment: Kindly accept the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using ansible inventory file. You can define a list and give as many values for source address as you want and iterate through them in your playbook.

In the inventory add:

```
source-address:
  - 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
  - 'yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy'
  - 'zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz'
```

In the playbook add a loop to iterate over `source-address` variable as:

```
- name: Rules
  rich_rule: rule
  family: 'ipv'
  source_address: "{{ item }}" 
  protocol_value: "icmp"
  with_items: '{{ source-address }}'
```

Notice the `with_items` in the above snippet. Here you are basically looping over the items of the list `source-address` defined in the inventory.

Hope it helps.